# Windows7 low power operating mode

Tags: windows-7

I need to leave my laptop open for running just one application. Is there some mode in which I can stop all useless processes and run only those that are required by windows?

***EDIT***: objective here is not to maximize the battery, but to use my resources conservatively. I don't know if that's a valid goal!

***EDIT***: Currently I'm using TuneUp utility's `economy mode` which essencialy turns off all useless services like `dwm` and all. Please suggest something that is better than this.

The thing is, I don't want my laptop to be running all day and night but at night when no-one is using the internet(it's a shared wifi internet), I can download Games and all at a better speed So at night, I need only the downloader to run, in the day I use my laptop for work.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid goal; just like turning off the light switch when you leave a room or turning your computer off, or putting it in standby, when you're not using it. Running a minimum set of processes + turning off your display + using a [DVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_voltage_scaling)- and [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling)-enabled processor should reduce your power consumption a good amount.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

safe mode is what I actually needed.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to get the maximum out of your battery. Some *extreme* ways to achieve that:

- Close all other running applications (check the taskbar icons too)
- Turn off your antivirus or any other scanning programs
- Put your laptop to "Power Saver" mode (Windows 7)
- Better, create a new power plan which sets the maximum processor, HDD, GPU activity to the lowest (-.-')
- Disable Aero and other effects
- Stop unnecessary services from the Task Manager
- Disable bluetooth
- Defrag your drive
- Avoid high temperature environments
- Disconnect USB devices (**!**)
- Don't place the laptop on soft surfaces
- Remove optical media
- Turn off the laptop screen or at least dim the screen

Still, I recommend just plugging in your charger! Overcharging doesn't damage your battery as much as heat does, its a common myth.

Try **BatteryCare**. It has lots of features to maximize power efficiency.

Maybe your battery isn't capable of holding full charge anymore, and is damaged. You can know that from BatteryCare. If the capacity is too low, you should replace your battery.

I don't suppose there are anymore options from which you can get a significant boost in efficiency.

Comment: I haven't found any answer yet which suggests more than what I'm already doing. Sorry!

Comment: Can you add some more information about what are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

### Software

Try [**Soluto**](https://www.soluto.com/). It list all software that runs on startup and shows you the load time per program or software that are set to run on startup, so you'll know which bogs down the system. It allows the user to disable the program or software from startup or delay it from startup.

### Windows 7 Services

Try [Black Viper’s Windows 7 Service Pack 1 Service Configurations](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-7-service-pack-1-service-configurations/). It lists which services can be disabled (in `services.msc)` to lessen the services that Windows 7 needs to run. It divides the recommendations into 'Safe', 'Tweaked' and 'Barebones', with 'Barebones' having the most services disabled but may cause more side effects or  "errors" reported in the Event Viewer. According to the author of the list, the 'Safe' configuration is the configuration that 95% of the people will be able to use with little or no side effects.

### Hardware

You could also disable hardware you don't use using the [Windows 7 Device Manager](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/f/open-device-manager-windows-7.htm).